# returning more than one method on submit html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i have two separate JS methods that validates the email and password.
My problem is that when i return both methods on the submit of the html form, the form passes even if the validation fails, but when i return only one method , it works absolutely fine!

```
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/" enctype="multipart/form-data"         name="form" onsubmit="return validateEmail(), checkPassword();">
<div class="reservation">
                <div class="section_room">
                <h5>Enterprise ID: </h5>
                <input name="enterpriseID" type="text" name="uName"    id="uName" placeholder="me@me.com" class="textbox" required>
                </div>

                <div class="section_room">
                <h5>Password: </h5>
                <input name="password" type="password"   name="PassWd" id="passWd" placeholder="Password1!" class="textbox" required>
                </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Login" style="width: 280px;">
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </form>
```

AND MY JS IS:

```
</script>
function validateEmail(){ 
var email = document.getElementById('uName');
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

 if (!filter.test(email.value)) 
 {
  alert('Please provide a valid email address');
   email.focus;
   return false;
 }
else
return true;
}
function checkPassword()
{
var pass = document.getElementById('passWd');
var re = /^(?=(.*\d){1})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%]{8,}/;
if (!re.test(pass.value)) 
{
alert('Your Password does not meet the minimun requirements');
email.focus;
return false;
}
else
return true;
}
</script>
```

Where have i wen wrong, or is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `onsubmit` to check against both values using a [logical AND (`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> When used with Boolean values, `&&` returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

```
onsubmit="return validateEmail() && checkPassword();"
```

Now if both `validateEmail` *and* `checkPassword` are true, this will return true. However if either are false it will return false.

Answer (score 2):

**Add some logic:**

```
function b(){return true&&false;} //false

function b(){return true||false;} //true
```

**You need to:**

```
onsubmit="return validateEmail()&&checkPassword();"
```